# Display kendoui treeview in kendoui grid

Tags: php, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I have a kendoui tabstrip having grids. and a kendoui treeview using js file.
How can I display this treeview in grid (Codeigniter, Magento - PHP)?